# .sendBeacon передает пустой запрос

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

Есть страница update с нее с помощью send.Beacon при закрытии страницы или перехода на другой url отправляю post id, чтобы потом по этому id найти запись в БД и изменить в ней переменные.

Код скрипта:

```
    function changeEdit(){ 
      var id = '<?= $model->id?>';
      var data = {id:id};
      navigator.sendBeacon("report/edit",data);
    };
    window.addEventListener('unload', chandeEdit);
```

В контроллере создал экшн.

```
public function actionEdit() {
$id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');
$sql = 'UPDATE report SET edit_on = 1 WHERE id = '.$id;
$connection = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
}
```

Глобальный $_POST почему-то пустой. Если передавать через ajax, то post есть, однако сервер не успевает обработать запрос.

Comment: а что документация хотя бы по sendBeacon пишет? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: url  пишется так же, как обычно ты пишешь это в адресной строке

Comment: Это ясно. Вопрос именно в том, куда отправлять и как там их принять, т.е. в контроллере это прописывать и создавать отдельную страницу для этого? Знаю как из формы записать в БД, а как фоном сделать запись в этом вопрос.

Comment: Со страницы ты отправляешь через форму, указывая в форме URL, где написан по сути контроллер и экшн.......ничем это не отличается. Ты всё так же должен отослать на контроллер и экшн что-то....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что .sendBeacon передает только FormData, blob и json.
Так что изменил строчку:

```
var data = new FormData;
data.append ('id',data);
```